# GridBagLayout and BorderLayout on JPanel Aligning

Tags: java, swing, awt, miglayout

In the below code, I have 2 layouts, GridBag & Border however, I have only been able to push everything on top using BorderLayout. I also want push everything to the very West and I have no clue how do I do that. Any Ideas?

I want everything to appear on the Top-Left side of the JPanel.

```
public class Opspanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6393281054430179953L;
    public Opspanel() {
        JPanel gridlayout = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridlayout.setLayout(layout);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gridlayout.add(new JLabel("Vendor ID"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        JTextField vendorid = new JTextField(7);
        gridlayout.add(vendorid, c);

        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        gridlayout.add(new JLabel("Email Date"), c);

        c.gridx = 1;
        JTextField emaildate = new JTextField(10);
        gridlayout.add(emaildate, c);

        c.gridx = 2;
        gridlayout.add(new JLabel("Email Time"), c);

        c.gridx = 3;
        JTextField emailtime = new JTextField(10);
        gridlayout.add(emailtime, c);       

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(gridlayout, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }
}
```

Thank you so much for making my life much easier with MigLayout. It works Perfectly for me. I have one issue though. Can you please help?

I want the "OPS Coordinator" which is docked at North, I want it to be centered vertically and horizontally both. But, I have been able to center in only Vertically.

```
public class Opspanel extends JPanel{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6393281054430179953L;
    public Opspanel() {
        MigLayout layout = new MigLayout();
        setLayout(layout);
        add(new JLabel("Vendor ID"), "cell 0 0");
        JTextField txtVendorId = new JTextField();
        add(txtVendorId, "h 20, w 100, gapleft 5, cell 1 0");
        add(new JLabel("Email Date"),"cell 2 0, gapleft 5");
        JTextField txtEmailDate = new JTextField();
        add(txtEmailDate, "cell 3 0, h 20, w 100, gapleft 5");
        add(new JLabel("Email Time"), "cell 4 0, gapleft 5");
        JTextField txtEmailTime = new JTextField();
        add(txtEmailTime, "cell 5 0, h 20, w 100, gapleft 5, wrap 15px");
        add(new JLabel("Subject Line"), "cell 0 1");
        JTextField txtSubLine = new JTextField();
        add(txtSubLine, "cell 1 1, h 20, w 600, span, gapleft 5, wrap 15px");
        add(new JLabel("Assigned"), "cell 0 2");
        JTextField txtAssigned = new JTextField();
        add(txtAssigned, "cell 1 2, h 20, w 150, gapleft 5, span 2");
        add(new JLabel("M-Manager"), "cell 3 2, gapleft 5, align center");
        JComboBox<String> cmbMM = new JComboBox<>();
        add(cmbMM, "cell 4 2, h 20!, w 150, gapleft 5, wrap 15px, span 2");
        add(new JLabel("City Name"), "cell 0 3");
        JTextField txtCity = new JTextField();
        add(txtCity, "cell 1 3, span 2, w 150, gapleft 5");
        add(new JLabel("Region"), "cell 3 3, gapleft 5, align center");
        JComboBox<String> cmbRegion = new JComboBox<>();
        cmbRegion.addItem("North");
        cmbRegion.addItem("South");
        cmbRegion.addItem("West");
        cmbRegion.addItem("East");
        cmbRegion.setSelectedIndex(-1);
        add(cmbRegion, "cell 4 3, h 20!, w 100, gapleft 5, wrap 15px, span 2");
        add(new JLabel("OPS Coordinator"),"dock north, align center center, span, h 70!, wrap");
    }
}
```

Comment: You may prefer this 3rd party layout manager [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/)

Comment: Use a combination of `anchor` and `weightx` and `weighty`